# $R_1$ paracompact spaces are normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, paracompactness

How to prove that an $R_1$ and paracompact space is a normal space?

To include definitions, let $X$ be a topological space.

- We say that $X$ is *paracompact* if every open cover has an open refinement that is locally finite.
- We say that $X$ is *R<sub>1</sub>* if any two topologically distinguishable points can be separated by disjoint open neighbourhoods.

  - We say that $x,y \in X$ are *topologically indistinguishable* if they have exactly the same neighborhoods. That is, if $x$ and $y$ are points in $X$, and $A$ is the set of all neighborhoods that contain $x$, and $B$ is the set of all neighborhoods that contain $y$, then $x$ and $y$ are "topologically indistinguishable" if and only if $A = B$.

    Otherwise we call $x,y \in X$ *topologically distinguishable*. This means there is an open set containing precisely one of the two points.
- We say that $X$ is a *normal space* if given any disjoint closed sets $E$ and $F$, there are open neighbourhoods $U$ of $E$ and $V$ of $F$ that are also disjoint.

Comment: You should be able to basically copy the proof that paracompact Hausdorff spaces are normal, noting that if $E,F \subseteq X$ are disjoint closed sets, then $x,y$ are topologically distinguishable for all $x \in E$ and $y \in F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a construction called the *Kolmogorov quotient* of a space $X$. This is the quotient space of $X$ by the relation $x\sim y$ whenever $x,y$ are topologically indistinguishable. The quotient map $q:X\to K(X)$ preserves almost all topological properties, which is not surprising since it induces a bijection $f_*:\tau_X\to\tau_{K(X)}, U\mapsto f(U)$, between the topologies, with inverse $f^*:U\mapsto f^{-1}(U)$.
In particular, if $X$ is paracompact, then so is $K(X)$: Given an open cover $\cal U$ of $K(X)$, this pulls back to an open cover of $X$, which has a locally finite open refinement cover $\cal V$, whose image is an open refinement cover for $\cal U$. It remains to show that $f_*(\cal V)$ is locally finite. For any point $y\in K(X)$, pick a point $x\in f^{-1}(y)$. This $x$ has an open neighborhood $W$ intersecting only a finite number of sets in $\cal V$. But then $f(W)$ intersects only finitely many images since $f_*$ preserves intersections (which follows from the fact that its inverse $f^*$ does).
Now $R_1$-spaces can be characterized as those spaces having a Hausdorff Kolmogorov quotient. So if $X$ is a paracompact $R_1$-space, $K(X)$ is a paracompact Hausdorff space, and therefore it is normal. This implies that $X$ is normal as well.