Showing that $R_1$ paracompact spaces are regular.
Currently, in $\pi$-Base it can't be deduced that $R_1$ paracompact spaces are fully normal. However, regular $\land$ paracompact $\Rightarrow$ fully normal is already included as a theorem. So, it would be sufficient to show that $R_1$ paracompact spaces are regular to deduce that $R_1$ paracompact spaces are fully normal. I was wondering about how to prove this.

Here is another way to see this.
Let $X$ be a topological space.  Open sets are saturated for the equivalence relation of topological indistinguishability.  So there is a one-to-one correspondence between open sets in $X$ and open sets in the Kolmogorov quotient $\operatorname{Kol}(X)$; and similarly for other concepts derived from open sets, like closed sets, open coverings of the space, locally finite open coverings, etc.  From there, it is easy to see that $X$ has the property of regularity iff $\operatorname{Kol}(X)$ does, and similarly for other properties like normality, full normality, paracompactness, etc.
On the other hand, $X$ is $R_1$ if and only if $\operatorname{Kol}(X)$ is Hausdorff.  And it is well-known that Hausdorff paracompact spaces are regular (and more).  So the result that $R_1$ paracompact spaces are regular follows by passing to the Kolmogorov quotient and back.

After writing this answer, I saw a link on the left with basically the same argument: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315614 (but note: concluding regular is actually stronger than concluding normal).

I really appreciate that you have answered with this alternative way, and for that other reference too. These help me to gain more comprehension of the Kolmogorov quotient.

Let $X$ be an $R_1$ paracompact space.
Let $C$ be a proper closed non-empty set of $X$ and $x$ be a point of $X$ such that $x \notin C$.
Let $y \in C$, we have that $x$ and $y$ are topologically distinguishable. So, as $X$ is $R_1$, there exists $U_y$ and $V_y$ disjoint open sets in $X$ such that $x \in U_y$ and $y \in V_y$. We have that $C \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in C}V_y$ and we have that $\mathcal{A} = (\{ V_y \mid y \in C \} \cup \{X \setminus C\})$ is an open cover of $X$.
As $X$ is paracompact, $\mathcal{A}$ has a locally finite open refinement $\mathcal{U}$ in $X$. So, there exists an open neighborhood $A$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $\mathcal{V} = \{B \in \mathcal{U} \mid A \cap B \neq \emptyset\}$ has finite cardinality. Let's suppose that $\mathcal{V}' = \{B \in \mathcal{V} \mid C \cap B \neq \emptyset\}$ is non-empty. Then, for each $D \in \mathcal{V}'$, there exists $y_D \in C$ such that $D \subseteq V_{y_D}$. Now, taking $A' = A \cap \bigcap_{D \in \mathcal{V}'} U_{y_D}$ and taking $B' = \bigcup \{ U \in \mathcal{U} \mid C \cap B \neq \emptyset \}$, we have that $A'$ and $B'$ are disjoint open sets in $X$ verifying that $x \in A'$ and $C \subseteq B'$.
We conclude that $X$ is regular.
